# How to manage memory in C interface for C++ implementation considering c++11?

Tags: c++, c, interfaces, libraries, memory

I have a library implemented in C++ which has a C interface. This C interface is, for all intents and purposes, the only way to use this library. C++11 seems to discourage the use of raw pointers but neither shared_ptr or unique_ptr are suitable in this case. From what I understand, intrusive_ptr is an option, but I am both unsure of how this differs from maintaining my own ref count (I am new to C++) and wary of wading into boost yet (I am new to C++).

How should I handle memory management in C++11 and higher? I only state the spec to make it clear that I am willing to use the features of the latest spec and have no need to maintain compatibility with older specs.

Comment: Why aren't unique or shared pointers suitable here? Unique and shared pointer between them should cover virtually every need you have, except when it comes to actually defining the C-compatible functions in which case owning raw pointers is necessary.

Comment: @DeadMG: that would have required the C code passing around *raw pointers to `shared_ptr<T>`* alike, which would have been opaque to the C code. How do you decipher an opaque address from a debugger?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that C++11 offers a range of smart-pointer classes to make life easier with memory management does not mean that you can't or shouldn't use raw pointers where that is appropriate.

The committee that maintains the C++ standard is very reluctant to remove existing features from the language and more so if it is a widely used and useful feature like raw pointers. Keeping the language backwards compatible is one of the corner stones in its evolution.

With that said, if you have to provide a C-compatible interface to your C++ library, you should use only features from the common subset of C and C++ in your interface and that means using raw pointers where they are visible in the interface and effectively letting the user of your library deal with allocation/deallocation (although you can provide functions for that).

Comment: If the library keeps ownership of a resource it would be fine to use smart pointers internally within the library and return raw pointers in the interface, no?

Comment: @ChrisDrew: You are correct. The trickiness arise when these raw pointers are jointly owned (shared) by both the C caller and some other C++ objects in the library.

Comment: @rwong, Yes, or if you want to safely transfer ownership from client to library, or vice versa.

Comment: @ChrisDrew: Yes, you can use smart-pointers internally. You just have to be very aware that when such a pointer crosses the interface, you are giving out an untracked reference. You must double check that the smart pointer doesn't clean up the resource too early.

Answer (score 1):

#### Analysis.

It has to use some kind of intrusive pointer (specifically user-implemented reference counting), though it could be Boost `intrusive_ptr` or some other flavor.

---

#### My personal opinion.

I have used Microsoft COM pointers in my projects and it works fine. If your code only has to work on Microsoft Windows, this may be the recommended route as the C systems programmer for Windows will probably be familiar with it. For all other considerations, including cross-platform applications, use Boost `intrusive_ptr`.

I have described my opinions about the minimal usage of Microsoft COM pointers [in this answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/74793/620).

---

#### The nature of intrusive_ptr.

It is important to understand the nature of `intrusive_ptr`. It is a handle class, implemented using C++ template. It is provided so that such objects can be owned by C++ callers.

C code cannot see this handle class from their header includes, let along call its methods. Instead, the C code would be calling some `extern "C"` methods. This means you will be providing `extern "C"` methods which in turn call the `intrusive_ptr_add_ref` and `intrusive_ptr_release` methods provided by Boost `intrusive_ptr`.

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/smart_ptr/intrusive_ptr.html

---

#### What this means.

Calling C++ methods on this object from C code will require one wrapper function per class method, [such as this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14815457/377657).

For objects that require `add_ref` and `release` management, you will provide `extern "C"` wrapper functions for those as well.

**It is your responsibility to document in an obvious way, or convey to the C programmer, what pointer types in your object are reference-counted.** A combination of naming convention, API documentation, API usage sample, and verbal warning is recommended.

**Finally, understand the laws (object ownership rules) that needs to be obeyed when using reference counting.** See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9856893/377657) and [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9868513/377657).

---

#### Advanced topics - object or interface type cast, interface query, interface segregation

I have only used these techniques with Microsoft COM (via its `QueryInterface` method), so I cannot comment on whether one could use these techniques on Boost `intrusive_ptr` when programming via an `extern "C"` interface.